# What is the purpose of app_name in urls.py in Django?

Tags: django, django-urls

When `include()`ing urlconf from the Django app to the project's `urls.py`, some kind of app's name (or namespace) should be specified as:

- `app_namespace` in `include((pattern_list, app_namespace), namespace=None)` in main `urls.py`

or

- `app_name` variable in app's `urls.py`.

Since, I guess, Django 2, the second method is the preferred one Although I copy-pasted first function signature from Django 3 documentation. But that's not the main point.

My current understanding of `namespace` parameter of `include()` is that it's what I use when using `reverse()`.

What is the purpose of `app_name` in app's `urls.py` or `app_namespace` in main `urls.py`?
Are these exactly the same thing?
How is it used by Django?

Existing questions (and answers) I've found here explain HOW I should specify it rather than WHY.

Comment: There is an [example in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) that explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this answer, I am taking the [DRF package](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and its [URL patterns](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/urls.py). If you want to try any of the snippets mentioned in this answer, you must install (`pip install djangorestframework`) and add `rest_framework` to `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

---

The ***application namespace*** can be set in two ways, [Ref: [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs)]

1. in `urls.py` using `app_name` varibale.

   You can see that DRF has set the `app_name` in [`urls.py`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/355afcf64b27a06c8b48c0291fa3eae61e0c3695/rest_framework/urls.py#L17). Django will use this `app_name`  as the *application namespace* only if we are included the patterns with ***module reference***.

   That is, [**`include(module, namespace=None)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#include)

   **Example:**

   ```
   urlpatterns = [  
    path('drf-auth/bare/', include('rest_framework.urls')),  
   ]
   ```
2. in [`include((pattern_list, app_namespace), namespace=None)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#include) function using `app_namespace` parameter.

   In this method, you can set an *additional `app_namespace`* for the application, if you want.

   Most importantly, we are passing a ***pattern_list*** instead of *module*

   **Example:**

   ```
   from rest_framework.urls import urlpatterns as drf_urlpatterns

   urlpatterns = [  
      path('drf-auth/foo/', include((drf_urlpatterns, 'foo-app-namespace'))),  
   ]
   ```

#### Complete Example

```
from django.urls import path, include, reverse  
from rest_framework.urls import urlpatterns as drf_urlpatterns  
  
urlpatterns = [  
  path('drf-auth/bare/', include('rest_framework.urls')),  
  path('drf-auth/foo/', include((drf_urlpatterns, 'foo-app-namespace'))),  
  path('drf-auth/bar/', include((drf_urlpatterns, 'bar-app-namespace'))),  
]  

print(reverse('rest_framework:login'))
print(reverse('foo-app-namespace:login'))
print(reverse('bar-app-namespace:login'))

#results
/drf-auth/bare/login/
/drf-auth/foo/login/
/drf-auth/bar/login/
```

---

> 1. What is the purpose of `app_name` in app's `urls.py` or `app_namespace` in main `urls.py`?

Both are used to set the ***application namespace***. The `app_name` can be used as a ***default application namespace***, if defined in the `urls.py`.

> 2. Are these exactly the same thing?

No.

> 3. How is it used by Django?

The ***application namespace*** and ***instance namespace*** are used to retrieve the URL path. In Django, whenever the [**`reverse(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) function get executed, Django looking for an application namespace first, than any other. You can read more about how Django resolve the URL here, [Reversing namespaced URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)

Answer (score 4):

`app_name` in app/urls.py and `app_namespace` in `include((pattern_list, app_namespace), namespace=None)` in main urls.py are the same referenced as [application namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#term-application-namespace) which describes the name of the application that is being deployed.

One can either pass the whole app/urls.py or a string reference of app/urls.py with app_name to `include()`

```
# blog.urls
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.post(), name='detail'),
]
```

```
# project urls
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

OR

a tuple of url patterns and app_namespace to `include()`

```
# project urls
from django.urls import include, path
from blog.urls import urlpatterns as blogpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include((blogpatterns, 'blog'))),
]
```

`app_namespace` will be the default application namespace when provided in `include()`. If `app_namespace` is not provided, then it will look for `app_name` in `blog/urls.py` and that will be the default namespace.

Without the app namespace, urls are added to global namespace which may lead to url conficts.

[URL namespaces and included URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) | [Term application namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#term-application-namespace) | [include()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.include)

Answer (score 2):

For years, we've (at Django) been skirting around the (confusing) distinction between an application name(space) and an instance namespace. We've always just recommended using instance namespace, as per the examples in the docs.

What's happened with Django 2.0 (and onwards) is they've made it so you can't use an instance namespace without also (first) using an application name. Instead of fixing code, we should update our examples to the correct usage.

The include needs to go like this:

```py
urlpatterns += [ url('API/', include((router.urls, 'pikachu')) ]
```

The tendency is to include the second `namespace='pikachu'` instance namespace parameter as well, but that's not needed — it defaults to None and is set to `'pikachu'` in this case automatically.

Generally, users want to be including an app-level URLs module explicitly setting the `app_name` attribute there, rather than including the router by hand.

Answer (score -1):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#introduction :

> URL namespaces allow you to uniquely reverse named URL patterns even
>   if different applications use the same URL names. It’s a good practice
>   for third-party apps to always use namespaced URLs (as we did in the
>   tutorial). Similarly, it also allows you to reverse URLs if multiple
>   instances of an application are deployed. In other words, since
>   multiple instances of a single application will share named URLs,
>   namespaces provide a way to tell these named URLs apart.

Comment: If I understand correctly this paragraph explains purpose of (instance) namespaces, not APP namespaces. The question is about the latter.

Answer (score -1):

**app_name** help in rectify **ambiguity** between same name(for urls) from different apps in a project.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34860303)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

TLDR;

app_name sets the namespace for the URLs of the current app. Namespacing is useful when you want to reverse URLs (i.e., generate URLs) using the reverse function. It ensures that the URLs of this app won't conflict with URLs of other apps.