# Naming of paths in Django for referencing in html templates

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I am a complete newbie at Django. I've looked around for projects on the internet with the hopes of trying to incorporate other django apps into those projects. Right now, what I am trying to do is to add a forum functionality into that particular project by installing Django-Machina. With the installation already done right, I am having trouble putting its URL into the base.html

Since Machina is a downloaded app using pip, it doesn't appear in the project as an app but instead in the virtual environment that I am using.

In urls.py of the `feed` app,

```
urlpatterns=[
  .
  .
  .
  path('forum/', include(machina_urls, namespace='forum')),
  .
  .
  ]
```

In `base.html` of `feed/templates/feed/base.html`

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'feed:forum' %}">Forum</a>
```

In Machina's guide, the URL configuration that the author provided was to update the main URL module in order to include the forum's URL. Thus, all i had to do was to add:

```
from machina import urls as machina_urls 

urlpatterns = [ 
  # [...] 
  path('forum/', include(machina_urls)), 
]
```

As of now I am having an error saying that I am specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported, and I fully understand the error. So how do I go about naming that particular path such that I am able to reference it in `base.html` ?

Thank you very much in advance and please let me know if you need any additional information. I will try my best to provide them.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use your django urls in templates:

```
app_name = "your_app_name"
urlpatterns = [
    path('your_url/', your_view, name="your_path_name")),
]
```

and you can use it in template like this:

```
{% url 'your_app_name:your_path_name' %}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying and i really appreciate it. However, I am still struggling a bit and am still slightly confused. Since I did not write the Machina forum, I'm not entirely sure how to change the app_name or which amongst the many should I change. What i intend to do is to basically add a forum functionality into my website. So its sort of like including a button in the base.html that leads to the Machina site such that all forum functionality will be handled there. Am i misunderstanding your answer? Please let me know! many thanks!

Comment: In Machina's guide, the URL configuration that the author provided was to update the main URL module in order to include the forum's URL. All i had to do was to add 

from machina import urls as machina_urls
urlpatterns = [
    # [...]
    path('forum/', include(machina_urls)),
]

How do i 'name' or reference that particular path in base.html?

Comment: hey, can u give me a link from machina url configs @kingsbane

Comment: https://django-machina.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html

here you go, thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I think this answer can solve your problem.check point no 2 --https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254816/what-is-the-purpose-of-app-name-in-urls-py-in-django

Comment: i think you need to register machina urls in your app_root/urls.py and it's app_name is forum for example u can use `{% url 'forum:index' %}

Comment: if you want to see all of your registered urls reverse, `pip install django_extensions`, and add `'django_extensions'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` then in your terminal type `python manage.py show_urls`, now find forum urls in the urls @kingsbane

Comment: @MojixCoder thanks for all the tips you've provided, I'll go and try them out and see if they work! is there anyway i can contact u? like email or something? that is if you don't mind!

Comment: Yeah, that's my pleasure. my email is mojixcoder@gmail.com  @kingsbane

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you didn't include machina app in installed apps

first of all you have to add machina dependencies and the machina’s own applications to your **INSTALLED_APS**  in your settings :

```
INSTALLED_APS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',

    # Machina dependencies:
    'mptt',
    'haystack',
    'widget_tweaks',

    # Machina apps:
    'machina',
    'machina.apps.forum',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation.forum_attachments',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation.forum_polls',
    'machina.apps.forum_feeds',
    'machina.apps.forum_moderation',
    'machina.apps.forum_search',
    'machina.apps.forum_tracking',
    'machina.apps.forum_member',
    'machina.apps.forum_permission',
)
```

then include it in your **TEMPLATES**  ,  **MIDDLEWARE**  and **CACHES**

and for urls you need to include machina app :

```
from django.urls import include, path
from machina import urls as machina_urls

urlpatterns = [
    # [...]
    path('forum/', include(machina_urls)),
]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, but i did do everything that you've mentioned. I got it to work if i did not reference it in my base.html, but what i am trying to do now is to reference it in my base.html