# Django URLCONF and reverse

Tags: python, django

I am trying to understand how django links the main urls.py with the url patterns of another application-Here in my case I have 2 apps: loginpage and signup.
I defined in the main urls.py this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('loginpage.urls')),
    path('signup/',include('signup.urls')),]
```

and this in loginpage.urls:

```
app_name='loginpage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.login_page_fetch,name='login_page_fetch'),
    path('Verification/',views.check_user,name='check_user')
]
```

I created a function in loginpage/views that get a template and fetch it:

```
def login_page_fetch(request):
    return render(request,'loginpage/login.html')
```

Now in my signup/views I created a function that created a user etc.. it will have in the end to redirect him to the login page:

```
def create_user(request):
    user=User()
    user.first_name=request.POST.get('firstname')
    user.last_name=request.POST.get('familyname')
    user.email_address=request.POST.get('email')
    user.password=request.POST.get('psw')
    user.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loginpage:login_page_fetch'))   *//*
```

I cannot understand starting from here *//* how django finds the login_page_fetch function-does he start looking in the main urls.py file to find a path where its mapped to loginpage.urls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Django URL resolver:

1. starts at the request's root URL resolver (generally just the main `urls` module, but could be different), possibly with knowledge of the current request's URL namespace to resolve namespaceless names to the current namespace
2. looks at each URL entry's namespace and name (walking "into" `include`s to find more entries) to see if they'd match what you're trying to `reverse`
3. if it finds a match by namespace, it tries to "fit" the parameters to the template, and if that works, you get the matching URL.
4. If all options are exhausted, an error is raised.

Comment: what you meant by walking into includes is that it will check in loginpage.urls if there is a namespace that matches what I am reversing-Once it finds that there is a var called app_name=loginpage tha tmatches with  the ' loginpage' in reverse it will automatically call the view function? and by default django will search for a variable called app_name that defines the namespace?

Comment: [The meaning of `app_name` in `urls.py` is discussed in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254816/what-is-the-purpose-of-app-name-in-urls-py-in-django)